# Using async/await in koa middlewares

Tags: javascript, koa

This does not work:

```
app.use(async function () {
   await something();
});

// AssertionError: app.use() requires a generator
```

While this works OK:

```
router.get('/', async function () {
    await something();
});
```

Any reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using Koa 1 - try `npm install koa@next`.

Comment: Yep, using koa@1.2.1 Gave a quick try to koa@2, and failed with stange build error... anyway, it is obvious to me now that v1 does not meat to use async/await with, because v2 is [on the way](https://github.com/koajs/koa/issues/533) to solve that. Thanks.